# How to restore the R built-in datasets?

Tags: r

I found some of my built-in datasets cannot show full columns.
For example, when I type the code:
    View(mdeaths)
I can only see the data below. However, I can see the full information of mtcars.

[mdeaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/foDxo.png)

Is it just me or this is a bug thing? Can I restore the datasets?

Comment: You have probably overwritten the name mdeaths. Try restarting R, which is Ctrl+Shift+F10 on Windows in RStudio. Alternatively, you can refer to the original with `datasets::mdeaths`

Comment: Hi Calum, not working. I have tried both methods. The columns are still unseen. Is there a quick way to restore all datasets?

Answer (score 2):

I commented without checking for myself. `mdeaths` is not in fact a matrix or dataframe, it is a `ts` time-series object which displays in a single column when called with View(). So this is not a bug, it is just how the dataset is provided. You can see that it prints normally if you call `print(mdeaths)`. If you want it as a matrix or a dataframe, you can convert it like so:

```r
matrix(mdeaths, ncol = 12, byrow = TRUE)
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12]
#> [1,] 2134 1863 1877 1877 1492 1249 1280 1131 1209  1492  1621  1846
#> [2,] 2103 2137 2153 1833 1403 1288 1186 1133 1053  1347  1545  2066
#> [3,] 2020 2750 2283 1479 1189 1160 1113  970  999  1208  1467  2059
#> [4,] 2240 1634 1722 1801 1246 1162 1087 1013  959  1179  1229  1655
#> [5,] 2019 2284 1942 1423 1340 1187 1098 1004  970  1140  1110  1812
#> [6,] 2263 1820 1846 1531 1215 1075 1056  975  940  1081  1294  1341
```

Created on 2018-07-03 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: You can also get close using one of the helper functions called by `stats:::print.ts` - try `.preformat.ts(mdeaths)`